# The summation $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^{-2k}}{k^2}=\text{Li}_2(1/\phi^2)=\frac{\pi^2}{15}-\ln^2 \phi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, fibonacci-numbers, polylogarithm

In a recent post

[Computing $\int_0^{1/2}\frac{\sinh^{-1}(u)}{u} \,du=\frac{\pi^2}{20}$, $\zeta(2)=\frac53 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n\binom{2n}{n}}{2^{4n}(2n+1)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4499713/computing-int-01-2-frac-sinh-1uu-du-frac-pi220-zeta2)

I evaluated the required Integral using a very interesting result that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{\phi^{-2k}}{k^2}=\text{Li}_2(1/\phi^2)=\frac{\pi^2}{15}-\ln^2 \phi,~~ \phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\qquad(*)$$
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Relationship_to_other_functions

The question is: How to prove (*)?

Comment: Looks like [this question statement](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389425/a-very-odd-looking-statement-about-zeta3-and-textli-2-left-frac1-va?noredirect=1) might be helpful.